# Stop apps to get my SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences to save login info that used for HttpPost requests.

The problem that I use directly this data to authenticate users with php, so if anyone create another app only for steal my app users SharedPreferences(username, password), how can I stop him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared preferences are placed on internal storage by default. This is private to your app. Other apps cannot access your preferences file. The exception is if the user has rooted their device and runs the other app with superuser privileges.

Comment: mmm but the user if rooted his phone, he can only steal himself? that's what I understand from you and from another questions on stackoverflow. thanks

Comment: @GagelGagel: "he can only steal himself?" -- apps that the user runs with superuser privileges can do what they want. *Usually*, that will mean that, at most, the user will simply view her own data.

Comment: Well, technically, as you said, apps that the user runs with superuser privileges can do what they want. So if user of the rooted phone is careless enough to install some app that traverses all shared preferences and sends information to the third party, anythin on the phone can be stolen and there is no way to protect from that other than by some sophisticated encryption.

Comment: @amoiseyev yes, anything can be stolen, nowadays no system is secured 100%. question: what about storing the user informations into a SQLite Database? is it secure?

Answer (score 0):

@GagelGagel: yet again: application ran with administrtive privileges can do *anything*. Literally - anything. You can try to protect from stealing data by encrypting informarion with your own key and your own flawor of encrytion algorythm - but it is more reasonable to sya "if you have rooted your phone and got your information stolen, it is your problem". Specifically to your question: no, SQL does not provide much of protection againd malitious software on the rooted phone.

Comment: I use the shared preferences to store a access token key for each user account that if stolen by another person, he can do anything like delete post, change info... I think there's no way to protect the shared preferences. MR @amoiseyev, thank you for the informations.